# Do you need a release form when photographing employees on behalf of their employer?

Tags: legal, business, model-releases

I'll be undertaking a photography project which involves photographing employees of a small company who are producing a food product using an artisanal process. The photographs will be used on the company website to show the production process.

Do I need a release form for each employee that will be photographed?

If yes, what should such a release include.

Country is United States.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not.

The company will want to have them, though (for their use of the photos).

Generally you need release forms to publish, not to shoot.

Comment: i would disagree. How do you know the employer will get the releases and how do you know if your photos get published somewhere other than the company web site.  *Cover your but* and get releases for everyone you shoot. I have worked on many shoots for photographers  doing just this, a company website, and the photographer ALWAYS gets a release from every person. I AM NOT A LAWYER, SEEK ADVISE FROM A MEDIA ATTORNEY.

Comment: If I am paid to take photos and the contract does not stipulate I have to provide releases there is no need to do so. Whoever contracts that out should handle his requirements properly. Covering idiots is not my job.